# If falling coconut has more momentum than a bullet then why bullet is more deadly?

Tags: momentum, mass, velocity

Imagine a coconut of mass 1kg is falling from a 10m tall tree, the momentum is around 14kg.m/s (I don't know how to format my work but just trust me)
and then the momentum of a bullet of mass 0.01kg is fired at the speed of 1000km/h is around 2.8kg.m/s (again I'm a human calculator)

So obviously the momentum of a falling coconut is 5 times the speeding bullet but the latter is much deadlier? I am trying to mathematically prove which is deadlier so perhaps should I just compare their velocities instead?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an application of physics and belongs to https://biology.stackexchange.com/

Comment: One of the reasons is the same as why a needle with a small push perforates your skin versus a heavy human on top of you does not: pressure, that is, force per unit area.

Comment: The physics question is sound, but I would wonder about the "deadliness". I certainly would not want to try that experiment myself. It sounds like serious head trauma is likely to occur.

Comment: *i don't know how to format my working* A link to the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is provided in Step 1 of the instructions every time you ask a question. You can learn the basics in a few minutes.

Comment: I’m voting to reopen because destructive shearing of tissue is more a biophysics topic than a biology topic.

Answer (score 3):

The deadliness of an object in motion generally depends on both its momentum and its kinetic energy. Momentum is a vector quantity that depends on the direction of the object, while kinetic energy is a scalar quantity.

Momentum is given by the product of mass and velocity (p = mv), and kinetic energy is given by half the product of mass and the square of velocity (KE = 1/2 mv²).

In your example, the coconut has a greater momentum than the bullet because it has a larger mass and a reasonable speed. However, the bullet has a much higher speed, and since kinetic energy depends on the square of the speed, the bullet will have a higher kinetic energy than the coconut.

The damage caused by a projectile is often more closely related to its kinetic energy rather than its momentum. This is because the kinetic energy represents the ability of the object to do work, in this case, the work of penetrating the target. The bullet, with its higher kinetic energy and smaller surface area, is more capable of penetrating a target than a coconut.

So, while the coconut has more momentum, the bullet is likely to be more deadly due to its higher kinetic energy and ability to penetrate. This is why bullets are more dangerous than falling coconuts, even though a coconut may have more momentum.

For example, let's consider a coconut with a mass of 1 kg falling from a height of 10 m. The velocity can be calculated by conserving energy.

Using 1/2 * m * v² = m * g * h and taking g=9.8m/s², we get v=14 m/s
So, the coconut hits the ground with the velocity of 14 m/s.

Its momentum would be p=mv=14 kgm/s while its kinetic energy would be 1/2 * m * v²=98 kgm²/s²

Now, let's consider a bullet with a mass of 0.01 kg moving at a speed of 1000km/h = 277.8 m/s

The momentum of the bullet would be
p=m*v=2.78 kgm/s

But, the bullet's kinetic energy would be
KE=1/2 * m * v²=386.14 kgm²/s²

So, while the coconut has a greater momentum (14.0 kgm/s) than the bullet (2.78 kgm/s), the bullet is likely to be more deadly due to its higher kinetic energy and ability to penetrate.

Comment: it might help if you show some numbers

Comment: Sure, lemme just edit it real quick

Comment: Thank you for verifying the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Material damage, including tissue damage, originates from [deviatoric stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor#Stress_deviator_tensor)—sort of a 3-D version of shear stress, although it can include non-shear elements.

Stress is ultimately a force applied over an area. The force lasts as long as the tissue acts to decelerate the striking body to be motionless relative to the tissue.

Small and pointy objects present a small area, which accentuates the stress. In extreme examples, the projectile passes entirely though the body because the tissue in the way is destructively perforated without bringing the projectile to a halt.

Large projectiles such as coconuts can crush tissue and induce shock hazardous waves in vivo but readily come to a halt because the inertia of the tissue blocks their path. Small projectiles such as bullets rip through tissue because of the large stress—the large force per area and thus the large induced deviatoric stress.

Kinetic energy, as described in another answer, isn't the deciding aspect. I hopped down a couple stairs today, and relative to my body, the kinetic energy of the Earth striking me was truly immense. Yet I continued without expecting or suffering damage.

And as you've pointed out (and from the Earth example), momentum can't be the deciding aspect either. The deciding factor is the deviatoric stress induced by the interaction, which is a function of the speed, mass, cross-sectional area, tendency of the projectile to fragment, and involved tissues, among other parameters.

Comment: I feel like you're missing a point when you say kinetic energy isn't a deciding aspect. If a body has a certain amount of kinetic energy, then a retarding force has to be applied to make that body stop. More the kinetic energy, more the distance covered by the body before it stops due to the retardation (and more the damage caused). I agree to the fact that the stress in tissues cause the damage, but this stress is mainly due to the retarding force which is against the bullet to nullify its kinetic energy.

Comment: As far as your example is concerned, you can keep hopping around stairs because the thighs are designed to be that way. The video below by Khan Academy could help you understand better:
https://youtu.be/cijR2pQhacE

Comment: The Earth has a impact kinetic energy relative to me of $10^{24}\mathrm{J}$ in the stair example, so I'd say I understand just fine: The kinetic energy of the object upon impact isn't the deciding factor. When one proposes a hypothesis, it's not enough to show an example where it works. One has to look for examples where it doesn't.

Comment: My first comment clearly explains why the kinetic energy is a deciding factor. Please clarify if there's any mistake with that. Also, I did include the fact about the bullet being made in a shape which helps it penetrate in my answer. I'm not disagreeing with your answer; I'm just stating that kinetic energy does matter.